# If it's true for $\textrm{rank}(A)=\textrm{rank}(A^2)$

Tags: matrix-rank

I am trying to prove this and found this may be not true in general.Does anyone have any ideas about the counterexample for this statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you so much.Was preparing for the exam,lol

Comment: Good luck to you.